# How to start kafka in multi-broker cluster mode with docker-compose?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
  services:
  zookeeper-1:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
  ports:
    - 22181:22181
  environment:
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
  ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
  ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
  ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
  networks:
  - zk_net


zookeeper-2:
image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
ports:
  - 32181:32181
environment:
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
  ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
  ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
  ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
networks:
  - zk_net

zookeeper-3:
image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
ports:
  - 42181:42181
environment:
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
  ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181
  ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
  ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
networks:
  - zk_net


kafka-1:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
ports:
  - 19092:19092
depends_on:
  - zookeeper-1
  - zookeeper-2
  - zookeeper-3
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19092
  KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 500000000
networks:
  - zk_net

kafka-2:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
ports:
  - 29092:29092
depends_on:
  - zookeeper-1
  - zookeeper-2
  - zookeeper-3
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:29092
  KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 500000000
networks:
  - zk_net

kafka-3:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
ports:
  - 39092:39092
depends_on:
  - zookeeper-1
  - zookeeper-2
  - zookeeper-3
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-3:39092
  KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 500000000
networks:
  zk_net:
   driver: bridge
```

When i trying to kill node-1 in docker and get number of nodes from my Java-code like this:

`DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster(new DescribeClusterOptions());
List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>(describeClusterResult.nodes().get(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));`

There is null number of nodes, because node-1 is down. But i thought that if node-1 is down, there is node-2 and node-3 alive, so it has to work, and return 2 alive nodes, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If would be helpful to see your with which properties are you creating the AdminClient and if you are passing all the bootstrap servers.